# Paypal - Dynamic Buy button to charge our clients customer

Tags: paypal

I need to implement a method where we can allow a clients customer to make a payment to the client via our website - all of which will be setup via our custom CMS.

Our initial plan was to use the following form script to generate a transaction and ask the client to add a return address to our website.

```
  <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="someone@someon.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2 x sessions">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50">
    <input type="image" class="btn btn-default nom paypalBtn" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="£50">
  </form>
```

This would potentially work fine - as we could dynamically add the value, business email and item name.  Though we are worried that any web savvy person could simply inspect the form in a browser and change the payment value to a more pleasing figure!  So we feel we need a better solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

Log into your PayPal account, click on Merchant Services at the top of the page and then click one Create Payment Buttons for your website. When you create buttons on PayPal they are hosted and secure.

Comment: Thanks Jared - our system will be used by many different clients to charge their customers - so a hosted payment button from our account would only go to us - which means we cant use this method

Comment: You can use their merchant ID rather than email, BUT the amount could still be altered